# Flexpaper/Flowpaper licence not working - still have 10 pages limit

Tags: javascript, flexpaper

I bought *Zine* flowpaper, I have licence key but it's not working. When I enter to my flowpaper account panel I see in example:

```
$('#documentViewer').FlowPaperViewer(
    { config : {
        SwfFile : "Paper.swf",
        Scale : 0.6,
        key : "my-licence-key",
..
```

But when I downloaded `FlowPaper Zine version 2.4.7` (for version `2.4.8` I downloaded empty archives) I don't have `.FlowPaperViewer()` method but `.FlexPaperViewer()`. And my key not working - I have still 10 pages limit.

Here they write I should republish my PDF: https://flowpaper.com/questions-and-answers.jsp?qa=3813/licence-code-has-no-impact

I don't what what mean *republish* - I builded new version of my site with **grunt**, downloaded via **git** and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Flowpaper tech support offers this suggestion to someone hitting the 10 page limit in a Drupal installation:

https://flowpaper.com/questions-and-answers.jsp?qa=4127/drupal-website-10-pages-limit

Their solution is to "Log in to the flowpaper commercial download area with the account details you received when purchasing your license and download one of the web server packages from there. If you don't want to rerun set up then you can replace the following files with the files (from one of the commercial packages) to get rid of the limitation:

js/FlexPaperViewer.js
FlexPaperViewer.swf (if you're using flash as format)

I hope this helps.